# Spring Data JPA Specifications, how to fetch @JoinColumn data within the only sql request

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i'm newbie to Hibernate, i mostly have been using jdbc. But i was given a project which broadly uses Hibernate and Spring Data JPA Specification api to make requests to DB.
But there is an issue: if entity has @JoinColumn it makes numerous of additional requests to DB (in case of use of the inner field).

```
@Table(name = "vm$bonus_acc", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"msisdn", "very_parent_group_id"}))
@Entity
public class BonusAccount extends BaseModel {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private VMGroup group;
```

For example if i fetch

```
    Page<BonusAccount> page = paginationService.formPageRequest2(req.getStart(), req.getLength(), bonusAccountDao);

    page.getContent().stream().forEach( bonusAccount -> bonusAccount.getGroup());
```

with content.size == 100, it will further provide 100 separated requests to DB. It loads DB a lot, and makes unnecessary requests.

I've found that it's possible to reach my need by the following way:

```
public interface BonusAccountDao extends JpaRepository<BonusAccount, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<BonusAccount> {

    @Query("select ba, ba.group from BonusAccount ba ")
    List<BonusAccount> getBonusAccountsBy(@Param("groupIds") Collection<Long> groupIds);

}
```

What it does, it makes an inner join select and fills the BonusAccount entity within only one select request.
BUT the thing is, that Specification api is used really broadly and it's too much headache to change  this way.
What i currently see that Specification is well fit to configure the 'where' clause, but i can't find whether it's possible to configure the 'select', so my question is:

**Is it possible to configure the 'select' clause same way as 'select ba, ba.group ...' above, within Specification api, to achieve the @JoinColumn field be fetched within the only request.**

My current Specification code looks smth like below:

```
public <T> Page<T> formPageRequest2(int page, int size, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> repo){
    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size);

    return repo.findAll(new Specification<T>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            //what it does, it configures the 'where' clause
            //it uses only the Root<T> and CriteriaBuilder for this purpose
            //and doesn't uses CriteriaQuery<?> at all, i suspect that it could be the key to my need, 
            //but not yet found
            return createPredicate(root, cb);
        }
    }, pageRequest);
}

private<T> Predicate createPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    ...
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to use eager fetch? using @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

Comment: What you ar experiencing is the N+1 query problem where for each element in a relation a new query is use to load the entity it can be configured to be less. Using eager will increase greatly the memory consumption of your application. The best option if you want to load sometimes the relation but not always it to define a new query with a JOIN FETCH, this will load in one query the root entity and the related ones

Comment: i don't want to change fetchType annotation from Lazy to Eager, because it will lead that EVERY time i'll fetch this entity, the JoinColumn will be fetched, it's not necessary behaviour.

What i need is: to fetch JoinColumn but only within current request, not any other.

Comment: Is the relation bidirectional?

Comment: no, BonusAccount does points to VMGroup, but VMGroup doesn't points to BonusAccounts in my models. Not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Is it possible to configure the 'select' clause same way as 'select ba, ba.group ...' above, within Specification api, to achieve the @JoinColumn field be fetched within the only request.**

Yes. You can configure more than just the 'where' clause using specifications. I may be oversimplifying your goal, but to select the BonusAccounts that belong to certain VMGroups (and include the group in the selection) your specification can be defined like this:

```
List<Long> groupIds = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L);

List<BonusAccount> bonusAccountList = bonusAccountDao.findAll(
        (Specification<BonusAccount>) (root, cq, cb) -> {
            root.fetch("group");
            return cb.in(root.get("group").get("id")).value(groupIds);
        });
```

Note that I used a lambda to decrease the code a bit. The resulting SQL is:

```
select
    bonusaccou0_.id as id1_0_0_,
    vmgroup1_.id as id1_1_1_,
    bonusaccou0_.group_id as group_id3_0_0_,
    bonusaccou0_.name as name2_0_0_,
    vmgroup1_.name as name2_1_1_
from
    bonus_account bonusaccou0_
inner join
    vm_group vmgroup1_
        on bonusaccou0_.group_id=vmgroup1_.id
where
    bonusaccou0_.group_id in (? , ?)
```

I don't know what is in your BaseModel, so I just added the 'name' properties to my entities for tinkering.

Some helpful references:

- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/criteria-api-fetch-joins.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-criteria-api-in-expressions

Comment: Yes! root.fetch(), that's what i've needed.

Thanks a lot! It works